# #define string cast to LPCSTR or std::string

Tags: c++

If I have a `#define GAMENAME "POSEIDON"` and would like to cast it over to either a LPCSTR or std::string how would I go about doing it 'properly'?

Fx:

```
m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    "GLClass",

    /* My GAMENAME #define goes here */
    (LPCSTR)GAMENAME,

    dwStyle | WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
    /* The X,Y coordinate */
    0, 0,
    m_windowRect.right - m_windowRect.left,
    m_windowRect.bottom - m_windowRect.top,
    /* TODO: Handle to Parent */
    NULL,
    /* TODO: Handle to Menu */
    NULL,
    m_hinstance,
    this);
```

Perhaps I am just taking a bad approach to this?

Comment: How do you use it as `std::string`?

Comment: `std::string thisString = GAMEWORLD; class->member(thisString.str())`;

I can get it cast over to a LPCSTR in the define using: `#define GAMENAME ((LPCSTR)"POSEIDON")` but I'd like it to be generic in the #define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#defines are processed by the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) so GAMENAME is not really a variable in your program. Use of casts as demonstrated the answer to your own question would seem to make the problem worse. Mike Dunn's second [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide2.aspx) on strings at Code Project explains why casts are not the best option. The [first article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/cppstringguide1.aspx) is also worth reading obviously.

You should be able to create a std::string like this:

```
std::string str = "char string";
```

Then create the LPCSTR from it:

```
LPCSTR psz = str.c_str();
```

In your program you would pass *psz* to *CreateWindowEx()*. Another thing worth thinking about is whether the game name really needs to change? If not it's better making this a constant.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Instead of a macro use a template called 'GAMENAME'.
template <typename T> T GAMENAME() { return T("POSEIDON"); };
```

Example use:

```
GAMENAME<LPCSTR>();
GAMENAME<std::string>();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`#define`s are simply used by the preprocessor to do a search and replace of the defined tokens used in the source code. So anywhere that you have `GAMENAME` that will be literally replaced with `"POSEIDON"` *before* the compiler even runs against your source code.

Really though, in C++ the best thing to use would be a `static const` variable. This will give your code much more descriptive meaning while avoiding the pitfalls of preprocessor macros. The biggest "downside" of this is that you have to place your static (non-integral) definitions in a translation unit as well as the header file:

```
// my_class.h
class MyClass {
public:
    static const char *kGameName;

    MyClass(const RECTANGLE &rect) m_windowRect(rect) {
        CreateWindow();
    }

private:
    HANDLE m_hwnd;
    RECTANGLE m_windowRect;
    HINSTANCE m_hinstance;
};

// my_class.cpp
const char *MyClass::kGameName = "POSEIDON";

void MyClass::CreateWindow() {
    m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        "GLClass",

        /* My GAMENAME constant is used here */
        kGameName,

        dwStyle | WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        /* The X,Y coordinate */
        0, 0,
        m_windowRect.right - m_windowRect.left,
        m_windowRect.bottom - m_windowRect.top,
        /* TODO: Handle to Parent */
        NULL,
        /* TODO: Handle to Menu */
        NULL,
        m_hinstance,
        this);
}
```

If you want to use `std::string` just replace that where I used `char *` and use `kGameName.c_str()` in the `CreateWindowEX` call.

By the way, `LPCSTR` is basically just a `#DEFINE LPCSTR const char*`

Answer (score 1):

LPCSTR = Long Pointer to Constant STRing, which is defined as a `const char*` (ie. a C-string). `"POSEIDON"` is a string literal and is of type `const char*` (ie. LPCSTR).

1. You could leave it as is and then when you need an `std::string` construct one like:

   ```
   std::string myString(GAMENAME);
   ```

   Or create a temporary `std::string` object (if an `std::string` isn't automatically constructed from a `char*` when it's needed):

   ```
   std::string(GAMENAME)
   ```
2. You could have a `const std::string GAMENAME = "POSEIDON";` and then wherever you need an LPCSTR you use the one returned by `GAMENAME.c_str()`.